# Javascript function being called repetively

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have recently encountered a problem on javascript functions being called repetitively. I have a button that would call a javascript method. In the method the webpage will get send and get a POST http request to a php script. However the webpage sends the same request every single second.

Here is the script:

```
function processLogin() {
  //console.log("requested")
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //console.log("Hey");
      //document.body.innerHTML+= html;
      console.log("encountered");
      //xhttp.abort();
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "csc.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("uid=" + document.getElementById("username").value + "&pass=" + document.getElementById("password").value);
  event.stopPropagation? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true;
  return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="height:100vh!important;">

<div id="lginMain" class="jumbotron add" style="width : 50vh!important;margin:0 auto!important; float:middle!important;position:relative!important;top:25%!important;">

    <div class="form-group">
        <h1 style="font-size:30px;">Welcome back</h1>
        <br>
        <label for="email">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="processLogin()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here is the network processes screenshot:

[You can see multiple calls, when the button is just pressed once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYg14.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how/where is `processLogin` called? clearly the function is called multiple times, posting just the function isn't nearly enough information - also, what is `event`? that looks like internet explorer specific rubbish

Comment: As I said, processLogin is called when the "submit" button is pressed. which passes on login information to the script to process. However the script is checking the login information in a loop.

Comment: yes, you did say that, but there is no `loop` in the code, so it must be something else that is causing this loop - I take it the HTML has some `onsubmit=` attribute in it? or are you using `someElement.addEventListener('submit', processLogin)` to attach the function to the event?

Comment: also, what browser is this happening in?

Comment: Both chrome and Brave. I also attached the html code.

Comment: if you change `processLogin` to just `console.log` something, with no XHR at all, does the problem persist? and what is the point of `event.stopPropagation? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true; return false;` looks redundant, as there is no reason to do either, since it's not a form submit, and there's no possible side effect of allowing propagation/bubbling

Comment: Is `csc.php` doing a redirection to itself? The screenshot only shows that there's network activity, it doesn't say that it comes from your function.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, It was my problem, as Jaromanda X said attaching an event listener would be solve the problem. Therefore deleting the "onlick" attribute and adding an event listener solves the problem.

Comment: yes, that's what doesn't make sense - but then, Chrome is full of bugs